# UITests not recording XCode (Version 12.5 (12E262))

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automated-tests

I am trying to record UITests using Xcode 12.5 using the iPod touch sim on iOS 14.5 (18E182).

The application appears to launch, the recording button changes to the stop icon as pictured below however no actions are recorded.

[image]

This wasn't working on the project I was working on so I created a brand new project to test this and there is the same issue, does anybody know what it may be?

Edit: I have also tried a sim running iOS 12, same issue.

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet? I am writing UITests with complex views and sometimes it’s tough to write these without recording...

Comment: For now I've just grabbed version 12.4 of XCode and fire that up to record, seems to work for now.